# Bot Framework Emulator works but Web Chat not does not

Tags: spring-boot, azure-web-app-service, botframework, azure-bot-service

I have a bot, built using the Bot Framework V4 in Java with Spring Boot, that is hosted on an Azure Web App and using the Azure Bot Service.

When connecting with the Bot Framework Emulator using ngrok it works just fine but when I try to use the Web Chat channel in the bot service I get this error

> There was an error sending this message to your bot: HTTP status code Unauthorized

When trying to open it in Teams using the Teams channel it also doesn't work.

I have left the MicrosoftAppId and MicrosoftAppPassword empty and have my messaging endpoint set as https://<name>.azurewebsites.net/api/messages.

Is there any way I can use web chat?

Answer (score 0):

When testing with a locally running bot (with using local url), you don't need to specify MicrosoftAppId/MicrosoftAppPassword within Emulator. But when the bot is deployed to Azure (OR testing when running locally but through with ngrok), you need to configure them in either the Web App configuration or in the application.properties file.